# disable IIS default output

Tags: node.js, azure, iis

I am using an Azure website (under the hood IIS) to run my NodeJS program.

I'm using the Azure CLI to see the output of the console so I can debug, but with every error response (400 and greater), IIS prints out a default error message:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<title>IIS Detailed Error - 401.0 - Unauthorized</title> 
<style type="text/css"> 
<!-- 
body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;} 
code{margin:0;color:#006600;font-size:1.1em;font-weight:bold;} 
.config_source code{font-size:.8em;color:#000000;} 
pre{margin:0;font-size:1.4em;word-wrap:break-word;} 
ul,ol{margin:10px 0 10px 5px;} 
ul.first,ol.first{margin-top:5px;} 
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;word-break:break-all;} 
.summary-container fieldset{padding-bottom:5px;margin-top:4px;} 
legend.no-expand-all{padding:2px 15px 4px 10px;margin:0 0 0 -12px;} 
legend{color:#333333;;margin:4px 0 8px -12px;_margin-top:0px; 
font-weight:bold;font-size:1em;} 
a:link,a:visited{color:#007EFF;font-weight:bold;} 
a:hover{text-decoration:none;} 
h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;} 
h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 
h3{font-size:1.4em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#CC0000;} 
h4{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 5px 0; 
}#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS",Verdana,sans-serif; 
color:#FFF;background-color:#5C87B2; 
}#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;} 
.summary-container,.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;} 
.content-container p{margin:0 0 10px 0; 
}#details-left{width:35%;float:left;margin-right:2%; 
}#details-right{width:63%;float:left;overflow:hidden; 
}#server_version{width:96%;_height:1px;min-height:1px;margin:0 0 5px 0;padding:11px 2% 8px 2%;color:#FFFFFF; 
background-color:#5A7FA5;border-bottom:1px solid #C1CFDD;border-top:1px solid #4A6C8E;font-weight:normal; 
font-size:1em;color:#FFF;text-align:right; 
}#server_version p{margin:5px 0;} 
table{margin:4px 0 4px 0;width:100%;border:none;} 
td,th{vertical-align:top;padding:3px 0;text-align:left;font-weight:normal;border:none;} 
th{width:30%;text-align:right;padding-right:2%;font-weight:bold;} 
thead th{background-color:#ebebeb;width:25%; 
}#details-right th{width:20%;} 
table tr.alt td,table tr.alt th{} 
.highlight-code{color:#CC0000;font-weight:bold;font-style:italic;} 
.clear{clear:both;} 
.preferred{padding:0 5px 2px 5px;font-weight:normal;background:#006633;color:#FFF;font-size:.8em;} 
--> 
</style> 

</head> 
<body> 
<div id="content"> 
<div class="content-container"> 
<h3>HTTP Error 401.0 - Unauthorized</h3> 
<h4>You do not have permission to view this directory or page.</h4> 
</div> 
<div class="content-container"> 
<fieldset><h4>Most likely causes:</h4> 
<ul>    <li>The authenticated user does not have access to a resource needed to process the request.</li> </ul> 
</fieldset> 
</div> 
<div class="content-container"> 
<fieldset><h4>Things you can try:</h4> 
<ul>    <li>Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP status code. For more information about creating a tracing rule for failed requests, click <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=66439">here</a>. </li> </ul> 
</fieldset> 
</div> 

<div class="content-container"> 
<fieldset><h4>Detailed Error Information:</h4> 
<div id="details-left"> 
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
<tr class="alt"><th>Module</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;iisnode</td></tr> 
<tr><th>Notification</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ExecuteRequestHandler</td></tr> 
<tr class="alt"><th>Handler</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;iisnode</td></tr> 
<tr><th>Error Code</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;0x00000000</td></tr> 

</table> 
</div> 
<div id="details-right"> 
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
<tr class="alt"><th>Requested URL</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;http://api:80/server.js</td></tr> 
<tr><th>Physical Path</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;D:\home\site\wwwroot\server.js</td></tr> 
<tr class="alt"><th>Logon Method</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Anonymous</td></tr> 
<tr><th>Logon User</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Anonymous</td></tr> 

</table> 
<div class="clear"></div> 
</div> 
</fieldset> 
</div> 

<div class="content-container"> 
<fieldset><h4>More Information:</h4> 
This is the generic Access Denied error returned by IIS. Typically, there is a substatus code associated with this error that describes why the server denied the request. Check the IIS Log file to determine whether a substatus code is associated with this failure. 
<p><a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=62293&amp;IIS70Error=401,0,0x00000000,9200">View more information &raquo;</a></p> 
<p>Microsoft Knowledge Base Articles:</p> 


</fieldset> 
</div> 
</div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

How do I prevent it from sending this output to the console? I want to get ride of all IIS logging and only use my nodejs logging.

I only have access the the web.config file and the Azure configuration section. I tried turning off logging in both sections, but neither worked.

here's my web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <!-- Visit http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2013/11/14/introduction-to-websockets-on-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx for more information on WebSocket support -->
    <webSocket enabled="false" />
    <handlers>
      <!-- Indicates that the server.js file is a node.js site to be handled by the iisnode module -->
      <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <!-- Do not interfere with requests for node-inspector debugging -->
        <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^server.js\/debug[\/]?" />
        </rule>

        <!-- First we consider whether the incoming URL matches a physical file in the /public folder -->
        <rule name="StaticContent">
          <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
        </rule>

        <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the node.js site entry point -->
        <rule name="DynamicContent">
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>

    <!-- 'bin' directory has no special meaning in node.js and apps can be placed in it -->
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <remove segment="bin"/>
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <httpProtocol>
         <customHeaders>
           <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
           <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,DELETE,HEAD,PUT,OPTIONS" />
           <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, access_token, Connection, Authorization" />
           <add name="Access-Control-Expose-Headers" value="" />
         </customHeaders>
       </httpProtocol>

    <!-- Make sure error responses are left untouched -->
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />

    <!--
      You can control how Node is hosted within IIS using the following options:
        * watchedFiles: semi-colon separated list of files that will be watched for changes to restart the server
        * node_env: will be propagated to node as NODE_ENV environment variable
        * debuggingEnabled - controls whether the built-in debugger is enabled

      See https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config for a full list of options
    -->
    <!--<iisnode watchedFiles="web.config;*.js"/>-->
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be the following section in web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Note that the mode's value is case-sensitive.

Comment: Hi Michael, I tried your suggestion but now IIS returns a 500 error message for every request

Comment: Let me rephrase that:  You want to add/incorporate the <system.web> paragraph into the existing file's <configuration> section... rather than replacing your existing web.config.  Does that make sense?